# Remove trigger reference from pipeline in azure data factory using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline  which has trigger associated in azure data factory. I am trying to automate some of operations in azure data factory using powershell commands. In one use case , I am blocked.

**Use Case:** User changed pipeline name which has trigger associated. (This is sample only, in reality many pipelines/triggers may be there in data factory, user may change single or many pipelines)

Trigger Name: **TRG_Test1**

Pipeline Name: **PL_Test1**

So TRG_Test1 trigger is attached to pipeline PL_Test1.

**Requirement:** user changed  name from **PL_Test1 to PL_Test1_Updated** , the associated trigger should be detach(remove) from pipeline and then remove pipeline and create new pipeline with new name and attach(associate) same trigger.

Note: There are no changes in trigger details, only pipelines details changed.

By workaround using powershell, I am able to identify for which pipeline has which trigger associated using powershell script. **But I am unable to detach pipeline before removing pipeline.**

**Error:**

***The document cannot be deleted since it is referenced by***

Set-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger : I am using this powershell command when trigger is detached from pipeline and changes to affect in pipeline.

**Is there any powershell command to remove only pipeline references?**
**Any alternative /Work around process to remove references of pipelines?**

```
    ## Detach/Update the trigger
   Set-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ADFDeployResourceGroupName -Name $triggerName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -File /$triggerName.json" -Force
                                        
    ##Remove Pipeline
    #Remove-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName $ADFDeployResourceGroupName -Name $PipelineFileName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Force
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to  remove the pipeline references in the trigger, please refer to the following code

```
Connect-AzAccount


$sub=""
$groupName=""
$factoryName=""
$triggerName=""

Select-AzSubscription -Subscription $sub

$sw=Get-AzResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/$sub/resourceGroups/$groupName/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/$factoryName/triggers/$triggerName“ -ExpandProperties


#remove the piplines reference
$pipName="Test" // the pipeline you want to remove
$sw.Properties.pipelines =($sw.Properties.pipelines -ne ($sw.Properties.pipelines|Where-Object{$_.pipelineReference.referenceName -eq $pipName}))

$s=Set-AzResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/$sub/resourceGroups/$groupName/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/$factoryName/triggers/$triggerName“   -Properties $sw.Properties -Force
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are champ. Worked perfectly.